# How can I use v-model and without mutating the value in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, immutability

I have an input that uses the `v-model` directive to control the data.  I need to watch said data and figure out if it's been changed.

When I `watch` the data, the new and old values are the same.  This is because the data is mutated, as seen in the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch

> Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.

How do I use `v-model` and NOT mutate the data?

Comment: What is the reason for watching the property? 

A `v-model` is essentially nothing but syntactic sugar for `:value=""` and `@input=""` within the `@input` you can specify a custom method and hook into the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate data value to track changes with `$watch`, rather than using the model bound variable. This gives you access to the previous value.

HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <input v-model="inputModel" type="text" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var vm = new Vue({
    "el" : "#app",
    "data" : {
            "inputModel" : "",
            "inputValue" : ""
    },
    "methods" : {
        "changeHandler" : function(a,b) {
            console.log("Updating \""+this.inputValue+"\" to \""+a+"\"");
            this.inputValue = a;
        }
    }
});

vm.$watch("inputModel",vm.changeHandler);
```

Comment: close. but you should use a computed value that compares `inputModel` to `inputValue`. That way you maintain the original value.